# MVC update DropDownListFor after button submit with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have one form that has 2 partial forms, one partial form is to create an ingredient from textbox input and adds the input to the database when clicking on a submit button,  the second partial form is to add a ingredient to a listbox from a dropdownlist

I can successfully create a new ingredient but only upon page refresh the newly added ingredient shows in the dropdownlist

Would it be possible to update the DropDownListFor unobtrusive with a jquery script?

Partial form for add ingredient:

```
@model Recepten.Models.IngredientSelectModel

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Add Ingredient")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIngredient, Model.Ingredients, "Select Ingredient", new { @onchange = "$('#SelectedIngredients').append('<option>' + $(this).val() + '</option>')" })
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Current Ingredients")
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedIngredients, new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedIngredients))
```

Partial form for create ingredient:

```
@model Recepten.Models.IngredientSelectModel

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateIngredient", "Recipe", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "create-ingredient", HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @id = "createIngredient" }))
        {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Custom Ingredient")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.addIngredient, new { @id= "addIngredient" })
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" class="default-btn small-button light-border"/>
        }
```

Comment: Use javascript to add a new `<option>` element to the dropdown in the success callback of the ajax call

Comment: Thank you! I have used this code: `onclick = "$('#SelectedIngredient').append('<option>' + $(this).val() + '</option>')"` and added it to my button I can successfully add items now to the dropdownlist but wonder how I can change the .val correctly to take input from the textbox instead of adding the button text value. I have tried $(#addIngredient).val or $(this).val("#addIngredient") but I get syntax errors

Comment: As I pointed out in one of your previous questions, what your doing here is wrong and a poor UI. But its just `$('#addIngredient').val()` to get the text of the textbox.